# Call function based on radio button value (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, function, if-statement

I have tried to make a function that calls other functions, based on the value of a radio button selected by the user. I've got a loop set up, but it won't call the other functions to be called. And I'm lost as to why it won't work.

This is what should happen:

1. User clicks a radio button.
2. *ButtonSelected* variable is changed to the radio button's value (a string).
3. User clicks "CLICK ME" and *TestFunction()* is called.
4. *TestFunction()*'s "if" loop runs.
5. If *ButtonSelected* matches "skill", *one()* is called; if it matches "rage", *two()* is called etc.

Steps 1-3 work. But when *TestFunction()* runs, it won't match any of the strings in the "if" loop match with *ButtonSelected*'s, so the following function is not called.

Here's the function with the loop:

```html
<body>
  <div id="radiobuttons">
    <h3>Radio buttons</h3>
    <form class="radiobuttons" id="RadioButtonList">
      <fieldset class="no-border">
        <legend>
          <h3>Pick a number</h3>
          <label><input type="radio" class="RadioEntry" id="skill" name="SkillTypeButton" value="skill" onclick="return PickRadioButton()">one</label>
          <label><input type="radio" class="RadioEntry" id="rage" name="SkillTypeButton" value="rage" onclick="return PickRadioButton()">two</label>
          <label><input type="radio" class="RadioEntry" id="damage" name="SkillTypeButton" value="damage" onclick="return PickRadioButton()">three</label>
          <label><input type="radio" class="RadioEntry" id="slip" name="SkillTypeButton" value="slip" onclick="return PickRadioButton()">four</label>
          <label><input type="radio" class="RadioEntry" id="five" name="SkillTypeButton" value="5" onclick="return PickRadioButton()">five</label>
      </fieldset>
    </form>
  </div>

  <div>  
    <!-- Clear radio buttons -->
    <button onclick="clearRadioButtons()">clear Radio Buttons</button>
<br>
    <!-- Run test function -->
    <button onclick="TestFunction()">CLICK ME</button>
  </div>

</body>
```

```js
    <script>    

    var ButtonSelected;

    // CHANGE VARIABLE TO RADIO BUTTON VALUE ON CLICK 

    function PickRadioButton() {
      ButtonSelected = document.querySelector("input[name='SkillTypeButton']:checked");

      // Send value variable to console

      if (ButtonSelected != null) {
        console.log("Radio button value is " + ButtonSelected.value);
        console.log("Radio button value type is " + typeof ButtonSelected.value);
      }
    }

    // TEST IF LOOP

    function TestFunction() {

      console.log("Radio button value is " + ButtonSelected.value);
      console.log("Radio button value type is " + typeof ButtonSelected.value);

      if (ButtonSelected == "skill") {
    one();
      } else if (ButtonSelected == "rage") {
    two();
      } else if (ButtonSelected == "damage") {
    three();
      } else if (ButtonSelected == "slip") {
    four();
      } else if (ButtonSelected == "5") {
        five();
      } else {
        console.log("No functions ran");
      }
    }

    </script>
```

I've also had the same problem when using a switch.

This functionality is for a TTRPG dice roller utility. In the full version, I want to use radio buttons to select the type of dice roll to be made. And then for the functions needed to make that kind of roll run to run when clicking a "ROLL DICE" button, instead of needing separate buttons for each.

I'm new to Javascript. And I'm using pure JS for this project. Adding in Jquery and the like is too confusing for me right now.

This is a JSFiddle of the test code. The results are shown in the console:
[Broken "if" loop](https://jsfiddle.net/rcosgrove/tp0zc4rv/13/)

Comment: Can you share the relevant HTML, so that we can see the problem you describe and help you with the errors/problems?

Comment: @DavidThomas Added the HTML now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `addEventListener`.

```
document.querySelectorAll('input[name=\'SkillTypeButton\']').forEach((radio) => {
  radio.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
    if (event.target.checked) {
      switch (event.target.value) {
        case 'option1':
          option1Func();
          break;
        case 'option2':
          option2Func();
          break;
        case 'option3':
          option3Func();
          break;
        default:
          console.log('Unknown option selected');
      }
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: I thought eventlistener would trigger the loop as soon as a radio button is clicked. I don’t want that to happen - clicking the button is the first step when using the roller.

Comment: I decided to use this eventlistener code, and a else if loop to activate the required set of code, as it was simple and effective. But I set the eventlistener to run on “change”, not “click”. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

The way I'm likely to approach this is as follows, with explanatory comments in the code:

```js
// a simple Object to map the <input> values to the desired functionality; essentially
// creating a list of functions named for the relevant values:
const functionMap = {
  skill: (evt) => {
    // function one:
    document.querySelector('body').style.setProperty('--color', 'rebeccapurple')
  },
  rage: (evt) => {
    // function two:
    document.querySelector('body').style.setProperty('--fontFamily', 'monospace')
  },
  damage: (evt) => {
    // function three:
    document.querySelector('body').style.setProperty('--fontFamily', 'system-ui')
  },
  slip: (evt) => {
    // function four:
    document.querySelector('body').style.setProperty('--color', 'lightskyblue')
  },
  5: (evt) => {
    // function five:
    document.querySelector('body').style.setProperty('--fontWeight', '800')
  },
}

// using EventTarget.addEventListener() to bind the testFunction to the 'click'
// event on the <button> element with a class of "clickHandler":
document.querySelector('button.clickHandler').addEventListener('click', testFunction);

// the function which serves to handle the click events:
function testFunction() {

  // retrieving the checked radio-input:
  const choice = document.querySelector('form input[type=radio]:checked');

  // if no element has been checked, choice will be null and therefore
  // falsey:
  if (!choice) {
    // without a chosen radio-input we return false; if - instead of, or
    // as well as, returning false - you wished to run a default
    // functionality, that could also be placed in here:
    return false;
  }

  // assuming that an <input> was checked, and found, we use bracket-notation
  // to access the relevant function, based on the value of the <input>:
  functionMap[choice.value]();
  
  // logging the chosen-value to the console:
  console.log(`Chosen radio-element value: ${ choice.value }`)
}
```

```css
:root {
  --color: black;
  --fontFamily: sans-serif;
  --fontWeight: 400;
}

*,
 ::before,
::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body>div {
  width: 80%;
  margin-inline: auto;
}

button {
  padding-block: 0.25em;
  padding-inline: 0.5em;
}

div:nth-of-type(2) {
  display: flex;
  gap: 1em;
  justify-content: center;
}

form {
  color: var(--color);
  font-family: var(--fontFamily);
  font-weight: var(--fontWeight);
}

input:checked+span {
  background-color: black;
  color: lime;
  padding-inline: 0.25em;
}
```

```html
<div id="radiobuttons">
  <h3>Radio buttons</h3>
  <form class="radiobuttons" id="RadioButtonList" method="#">
    <fieldset class="no-border">
      <legend>
        <h3>Pick a number</h3>
      </legend>
      <label>
        <input type="radio" class="RadioEntry" id="skill" name="SkillTypeButton" value="skill">
        <!-- wrapped the label's text in an element in order to permit styling of the
             chosen-input's associate text when the radio is chosen -->
        <span class="labelText">one</span>
      </label>
      <label>
        <input type="radio" class="RadioEntry" id="rage" name="SkillTypeButton" value="rage">
        <span class="labelText">two</span>
      </label>
      <label>
        <input type="radio" class="RadioEntry" id="damage" name="SkillTypeButton" value="damage">
        <span class="labelText">three</span>
      </label>
      <label>
        <input type="radio" class="RadioEntry" id="slip" name="SkillTypeButton" value="slip">
        <span class="labelText">four</span>
      </label>
      <label>
        <input type="radio" class="RadioEntry" id="five" name="SkillTypeButton" value="5">
        <span class="labelText">five</span>
      </label>
    </fieldset>
  </form>
</div>

<div>
  <!-- Clear radio buttons -->
  <!-- using the 'form' attribute (with the attribute-value set to the id of the
       <form> upon which we wish to act), and 'type="reset"' to reset the form/radio-buttons -->
  <button form="RadioButtonList" type="reset">Clear radio buttons</button>

  <!-- Run test function -->
  <!-- removed the inline event-handler: -->
  <button type="button" class="clickHandler">Click me</button>
</div>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/oycz07mh/).

References:

- [Arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).
- [Bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors#bracket_notation).
- [`CSSStyleDeclaration.setProperty()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleDeclaration/setProperty).
- [`document.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector).
- [`EventTarget.addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener).

Comment: Thanks for doing all that. What would the advantage of the first step (creating the object)?